# View using views content pane not updating on node save

Tags: panels, chaos-tool-suite

On the home page, I have a view content pane to display the latest 3 blog items.  When I save a new blog node I don't see my new item on the home page. The only way to get it to show up is to flush all cache.

Any way to force the cache on the home page alone to clear when the node is saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Views content cache](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_content_cache) module.  It allows you to expire the views cache on add/edit/delete of nodes in your view.

Also, be sure to look at the Panels caching on your home page, whether that be in Page Manager, or Panelizer, you can set caching on items in Panels using the [Panels Content Cache](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels_content_cache) module.